# No puedo conectar con mi cluster de Mongo con node

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

me he decidido a crear una pregunta porque no me han servido las otras que he encontrado al respecto. Acabo de ponerme con todo este tema de MOngo y node, así que os pido paciencia. Tengo el siguiente script en javascript:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = "mongodb+srv://<user>:<pass>@cluster0-7q1pt.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(url, { useNewUrlParser: true});

client.connect(err => {
    const data = client.db("DB0");
    data.collection("FirstTable");
    if (err) throw err;
    //instrucciones que no vienen al caso
    client.close();
});
```

Cuando lo ejecuto vía shell con "node miarchivo.js" me devuelve el siguiente error: "MongoClient must be connected before calling MongoClient.prototype.db"

¿Alguien sabe por qué puede ser? Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Según tu código, veo que esta mal la url y como te conectas.

Te pongo un ejemplo por si te puede ayudar:

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb')
const user = '****' //Tu nombre de usuario
const password = '****' //Tu contraseña
const url = `mongodb+srv://${user}:${password}@cluster0-7q1pt.mongodb.net`
const options = {useNewUrlParser: true, w: 'majority'} //Opciones para la connexion.

MongoClient.connect(url, options) //Realizamos la conexión a la URL con sus opciones
    .then(async (conn) => { //Usamos async/await para resolver las promesas

        const db = await conn.db('DB0') //Conexión a la DB  

        const collection = await db.collection('FirstTable') //Conexión a la Colección  

        const count = await collection.countDocuments() //Un ejemplo, saber el numero de documentos de la colección

        console.log('Numbers Documents: ', count)

        await conn.close() //Cerramos la conexión
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err.stack)
        process.exit(1)
    })
```

Esto es un ejemplo de cómo conectarse a MongoDB, si navegas podrías ver mas ejemplos, todo depende de cómo necesitas usarlo en tu proyecto.

Espero que te haya podido ayudarte y, sobre todo, resolver tu problema.

Un saludo

[Documentación de MongoClient](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html)